If $x$ does not belong of any associated prime of $R/I$ then $(x)I = (x) \cap I$.
Let $R$ noetherian ring commutative with unity, $x \in R$ and $I \subset R$ ideal. If $x$ does not belong of any associated prime of $R/I$ then $(x)I = (x) \cap I$.
We know, in particular $(x)I \subset (x) \cap I$. If we suposse $I$ is prime then $Ass(R/I) =\{I\}$ then $x \notin I$. Let $y \in (x) \cap I$ then $y=rx \in I$ since $I$ is prime then $r \in I$ and $x \in (x)$ so $y \in (x)I$ how could I generalize? Could you help me?

The point is that $x$ is a nonzerodivisor on $R/I$ (why?). So if $y=rx\in (x)\cap I$, then $rx\in I$,so $r\in I$.
